# Compare a pyspark dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 data frames to compare both have the same number of columns and the comparison result should have the field that is mismatching and the values along with the ID.

Dataframe one

```
+-----+---+--------+
| name| id|    City|
+-----+---+--------+
|  Sam|  3| Toronto|
| BALU| 11|     YYY|
|CLAIR|  7|Montreal|
|HELEN| 10|  London|
|HELEN| 16|  Ottawa|
+-----+---+--------+
```

Dataframe two

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|Expected_name|Expected_id|Expected_City|
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|          SAM|          3|      Toronto|
|         BALU|         11|          YYY|
|        CLARE|          7|     Montreal|
|        HELEN|         10|        Londn|
|        HELEN|         15|       Ottawa|
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Expected Output

```
+---+------------+--------------+-----+
| ID|Actual_value|Expected_value|Field|
+---+------------+--------------+-----+
|  7|       CLAIR|         CLARE| name|
|  3|         Sam|           SAM| name|
| 10|      London|         Londn| City|
+---+------------+--------------+-----+
```

Code

#### Create example data

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext()
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR") # log only on fails

df_Actual = sql_context.createDataFrame(
    [("Sam", 3,'Toronto'), ("BALU", 11,'YYY'), ("CLAIR", 7,'Montreal'), 
     ("HELEN", 10,'London'), ("HELEN", 16,'Ottawa')],
    ["name", "id","City"]
)

df_Expected = sql_context.createDataFrame(
     [("SAM", 3,'Toronto'), ("BALU", 11,'YYY'), ("CLARE", 7,'Montreal'), 
      ("HELEN", 10,'Londn'), ("HELEN", 15,'Ottawa')],
     ["Expected_name", "Expected_id","Expected_City"]
)
```

#### Create empty dataframe for Result

```
field = [
    StructField("ID",StringType(), True),
    StructField("Actual_value", StringType(), True), 
    StructField("Expected_value", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Field", StringType(), True)
]

schema = StructType(field)
Df_Result = sql_context.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
```

#### Join expected and actual on id's

```
df_cobined = df_Actual.join(df_Expected, (df_Actual.id == df_Expected.Expected_id))

col_names=df_Actual.schema.names
```

#### Loop through each column to find mismatches

```
for col_name in col_names:

    #Filter for column values not matching
    df_comp= df_cobined.filter(col(col_name)!=col("Expected_"+col_name ))\
        .select(col('id'),col(col_name),col("Expected_"+col_name ))

    #Add not matching column name
    df_comp = df_comp.withColumn("Field", lit(col_name))

    #Add to final result
    Df_Result = Df_Result.union(df_comp)
Df_Result.show()
```

This code works as expected. However, in the real case, I have more columns and millions of rows to compare. With this code, it takes more time to finish the comparison. Is there a better way to increase the performance and get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this who are looking for an answer, I transposed the data frame and then did a comparison.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, col, explode, struct, lit
def Transposedf(df, by,colheader):

# Filter dtypes and split into column names and type description
cols, dtypes = zip(*((c, t) for (c, t) in df.dtypes if c not in by))
# Spark SQL supports only homogeneous columns
assert len(set(dtypes)) == 1, "All columns have to be of the same type"

# Create and explode an array of (column_name, column_value) structs
kvs = explode(array([ struct(lit(c).alias("Field"), col(c).alias(colheader)) for c in cols ])).alias("kvs")

return df.select(by + [kvs]).select(by + ["kvs.Field", "kvs."+colheader])
```

---

Then  the comparison looks like this

```
def Compare_df(df_Expected,df_Actual):
  df_combined = (df_Actual
    .join(df_Expected, ((df_Actual.id == df_Expected.id) 
                        & (df_Actual.Field == df_Expected.Field) 
                        & (df_Actual.Actual_value != df_Expected.Expected_value)))
    .select([df_Actual.account_unique_id,df_Actual.Field,df_Actual.Actual_value,df_Expected.Expected_value])
    )
      return df_combined
```

I called these 2 functions as

```
df_Actual=Transposedf(df_Actual, ["id"],'Actual_value')
df_Expected=Transposedf(df_Expected, ["id"],'Expected_value')

#Compare the expected and actual
df_result=Compare_df(df_Expected,df_Actual)
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to avoid doing the `union` is the following:

- Create a list of columns to compare: `to_compare`
- Next select the `id` column and use `pyspark.sql.functions.when` to compare the columns. For those with a mismatch, build an array of structs with 3 fields: `(Actual_value, Expected_value, Field)` for each column in `to_compare`
- Explode the temp array column and drop the nulls
- Finally select the `id` and use `col.*` to expand the values from the struct into columns.

Code:

`StructType` to store the mismatched fields.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

# these are the fields you want to compare
to_compare = [c for c in df_Actual.columns if c != "id"]

df_new = df_cobined.select(
        "id", 
        f.array([
            f.when(
                f.col(c) != f.col("Expected_"+c), 
                f.struct(
                    f.col(c).alias("Actual_value"),
                    f.col("Expected_"+c).alias("Expected_value"),
                    f.lit(c).alias("Field")
                )
            ).alias(c)
            for c in to_compare
        ]).alias("temp")
    )\
    .select("id", f.explode("temp"))\
    .dropna()\
    .select("id", "col.*")
df_new.show()
#+---+------------+--------------+-----+
#| id|Actual_value|Expected_value|Field|
#+---+------------+--------------+-----+
#|  7|       CLAIR|         CLARE| name|
#| 10|      London|         Londn| City|
#|  3|         Sam|           SAM| name|
#+---+------------+--------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks @pault , I will try this way and let you know

Comment: @pault, which Python library is used here?

Answer (score 1):

Join only those records where expected id equals actual and there is mismatch in any other column:

```
df1.join(df2, df1.id=df2.id and (df1.name != df2.name or df1.age != df2.age...))
```

This means you will do for loop only across mismatched rows, instead of whole dataset.